# Google Cloud Vision API hangs when used inside app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to run the sample code for google's cloud vision API from the official quick start guide (Java): https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

When running in a standalone program, everything works as expected. If I run the exact same code inside app engine's local dev server, the call to "vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);" hangs. It doesn't throw any exception and there is no running thread. It never times out (I left it running for ~20 minutes once). Pausing all threads in the debugger only shows threads waiting.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Nope. I gave up on using the client libraries and made a direct HTTP request to the REST API, which seems to work reliably.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. You might consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, but from an AWS server.

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to make calls to Cloud Vision API, a service hosted in the Cloud, not locally on your machine. You may check the "Quickstart" [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart) for more insight.