# Google cloud vision Python client times out when request comes from from Cloud run service

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-vision

I have a Python application (using Flask) which uses the Google Cloud Vision API client (via [pip package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/) `google-cloud-vision`) to analyze images for text using OCR (via `TEXT_DETECTION` feature in the API). This works fine when run locally providing Google credentials on the command line via `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to the JSON file I got from a service account in my project with access to the Vision API. It also works fine locally in a Docker container, when the same JSON file is injected via a volume (following the recommendations in the [Cloud run docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#docker-with-google-cloud-access)).

However, when I deploy my application to Cloud run, the same code fails to successfully make a request to the Cloud Vision API in a timely manner, and eventually times out. (the Flask app returns an HTTP 504) Then the container seems to become unhealthy: all subsequent requests (even those not interacting with the Vision API) also time out.

In the Cloud run logs, the last thing logged appears to be related to Google cloud authentication:

```
DEBUG:google.auth.transport.requests:Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
```

I believe my project is configured correctly to access this API: as already stated I can use the API locally via the environment variable. And the service is running in Cloud Run using this same service account (at least I believe it is, `serviceAccountName` field in the YAML tab matches, and I'm deploying it via `gcloud run deploy --service-account ...`)

Furthermore, the application can access the same Vision API without using the official Python client (locally and in Cloud run), when accessed using an API key and a plain HTTP POST via `requests` package. So the Cloud run deploy seems to be able to make this API call and the project has access. But there is something wrong with the project in the context of the combination of Cloud run and the official Python client.

I admit this is basically a duplicate of this [4 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049544/google-cloud-vision-api-hangs-when-used-inside-app-engine). But aside from being old that has no resolution and I hope I can provided more details that might help get a good answer. I would much prefer to use the official client

Comment: Please share more logs. Try this inside Cloud Run: `import os`  
`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/service_account_json.json"` Get this JSON file in IAM / Service accounts /keys . Tell me if it works.

Comment: @razimbres thank you for taking the time to read and respond. I'm confused because I don't think that should be necessary? in fact the [Cloud Run documentation explicitly says to never do that:](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity) "Never set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable on a Cloud Run service". The only other logs are from gunicorn starting up and I don't think will help

Comment: I've edited to clarify that the app is running in Cloud Run with a specific service account that can access Vision API, reading the linked docs I don't think it uses the environment variable as I had previously written in the question, but the client should automatically detect the runtime service account